# include header and footer in html created with xslt transformation

Tags: html, xslt

I'm creating an HTML using XSLT transformation run on xml content. The xml content is dynamic hence the resultant HTML can spread over more than one page. I would like to include a header and footer in each output page of HTML. Is there a way to do this XSLT transformation or HTML tricks ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the XSL generating more than one HTML file? If so, you can definitely include a header and footer in each HTML file.

If you’re only generating one HTML document, there isn’t really the concept of a “page”, unless you mean the series of screens a user sees as they scroll down. In that case, you’d need to use CSS to make the header and footer stay visible.

Or is this HTML being used to generate a PDF? Please explain further.

Comment: the result is going to be just one html document. Now understand that there is no page concept in an HTML document. What I need to create is a report with the data pulled from database and render it in page format with each page having a header and footer. Is PDF creation is only my option in this case?

Comment: I just don’t know what you mean by “page format”. Can you explain what that looks like in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I had an **XML** structure like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<documentElement>
    <header/>
    <body>
        <!-- omitted for brevity -->
    </body>
</documentElement>
```

and a **stylesheet** to transform the above XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:import href="imported.xsl"/>

    <xsl:output
        method="html"
        encoding="UTF-8"
        omit-xml-declaration="yes"
        doctype-system="about:blank"
        indent="no"
        media-type="text/html"
    />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="documentElement">
        <HTML dir="ltr">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </HTML>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="body">
        <BODY>
            <!-- content of other element -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="footer"/>
        </BODY>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which imports **another stylesheet**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!-- imported.xsl -->

    <xsl:output
        method="html"
        encoding="UTF-8"
        indent="no"
        media-type="text/html"
    />

    <xsl:template match="header">
        <!-- content of header -->
        <HEAD>
            <META charset="UTF-8"/>
        </HEAD>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="footer">
        <FOOTER>
            <!-- content of footer -->
        </FOOTER>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

would result in:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML dir="ltr">
    <HEAD>
        <META charset="UTF-8">
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <!-- content of other element -->
        <FOOTER>
            <!-- content of footer -->
        </FOOTER>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Notice the document has the **<header/>** element but not the **<footer/>** element and how the stylesheet(s) transform(s) them differently; e.g, <xsl:template **match**="header"/> versus <xsl:template **name**="footer"/>!

I don't know if this clears your doubt; in case you need in-depth explanation, do not hesitate to let me know :)

Comment: hello, I am having some trouble understanding this. can you help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43630649/how-to-include-header-xsl-into-another-xsl