# Footers in XSLT (xml-html-pdf transormation)

Tags: java, xslt

Is there a way to add a footer on the generated pdf file using the xslt transformation?

I use this code to transform object to xml, xml to html and html to pdf:

```
    ObjectModel obj = new Object();
    File file = new File("test.xml");
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectModel.class);
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();


    // output pretty printed
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(obj, file);
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(obj, System.out);



    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource("cert.xsl"));
    transformer.transform(new StreamSource("test.xml"),new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream("sample.html")));
    String File_To_Convert = "sample.html";
    String url = new File(File_To_Convert).toURI().toURL().toString();
    System.out.println(""+url);
    String HTML_TO_PDF = "ConvertedFile.pdf";
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(HTML_TO_PDF);       
    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    renderer.setDocument(url);      
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(os);        
    os.close();
```

the xsl file is as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java"
            exclude-result-prefixes="java"
            version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
            doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body style="font-family:Book Antiqua;">
            //content here


        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

I want to know if its possible to add footers in this transformation. I have found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616773/include-header-and-footer-in-html-created-with-xslt-transformation) but im still lost on how to do it.

Comment: add your input XML file in the query to resolve it

Comment: Static footers? Or dynamically created? I mean: Do you want to just add something like "Created by XYZ , Manufacturer.com (c)2016" or something including the actual date, original filename or something like that?

Comment: You seem to use use XSLT to transform your XML to XHTML and then some `ITextRenderer` software to transform the XHTML to PDF. You might want to tag your question in relation to that software. As for (X)HTML and paged media, https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#populating-margin-boxes is an attempt to specify a way to populate a footer, I don't know how well that is supported, and certainly not whether your software supports it.

Comment: CSS for print media has some support; did not find a succinct example but look here http://www.w3.org/TR/css-gcpm-3/#running-elements

Answer (score 0):

You can make a direct XML to PDF transformation via [Apache FOP](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/download.html).

With XSL-FO, the `static-content` allows you to make some headers and footers.

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="main">
  <fo:static-content flow-name="header">
    <xsl:call-template name="MyHeader"/>
  </fo:static-content>
  <fo:static-content flow-name="footer">
    <xsl:call-template name="MyFooter"/>
  </fo:static-content>
  <fo:flow>
    ...
  </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
```